# What Relational Databases can Store XML as a Native Type?

Tags: xml, database, jdbc, content-management-system

I'm investigating approaches for CMS content storage that don't involve [entity attribute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) models or NoSQL. Some of the problems I'm trying to solve:

1. No DDL for new types
2. Specifying the datatype of a particular node's text() (DTD association?)
3. Querying over JDBC with DDL (e.g. xquery + SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) not an OO programming API so the client deals with record sets.
4. Data import/export
5. Any scaling/performance concerns

As I've not found a comparable question, and if this is well received, I will curate and make a community wiki.

Comment: Interested in those solutions that work over JDBC instead of a separate API because querying may involve clauses that work with non XML data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Sql Server 2005 you have the ability to store XML as a native type. Not only this, but you can also create Schemas and add them to the the database to validate the XML being inserted into the aforementioned XML column type.

In addition to the XML type, SQL Server 2005 and 2008 add better support for returning XML using queries when compared to the way you did it with Sql Server 2000 and `FOR XML AUTO`.

**UPDATE**

Following are two pages that might be of benefit:

[White Paper: What's New for XML in SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/wp-sql-2008-whats-new-xml.aspx)

[Implementing XML in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx)

Comment: Does XML schema storage mean dates can be queried easily?

Comment: @orangepips The schema is more about validating the XML that you are inserting into the column. The good thing about the Sql Server option, is that you can download the express edition of the database to test that everything works. All the same XML goodness is available in the free express edition of Sql Server. Also, I have updated my post to include two pages that go into more detail about XML in Sql Server including limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-083851.html) in the past. It supports XML Schema and XQuery directly, and it's built on top of Berkeley DB so it should scale pretty well, although I haven't used it in a large-scale context.

Comment: +1 for proving some detail. After a brief read-through, it appears this is not using JDBC to work with XML data, but rather a separate API?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle (since version 9i). Look here

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm

for further information.